# Final adjustment needed for collapsible menu (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

```
      function collapseAll() {
                $(".cmenu > li > a ").each(function() {
                    $(this).addClass("collapsed");
                    $(this).find("+ ul").each(function() {
                        $(this).css("display","none");
                        })
                    })
                }
      $(document).ready(function () {
        var handleCollapsibleMenu = function (e, menu) {
            var expanded = e.parent().parent().find('> li > a.expanded').not(e);
            expanded.removeClass('expanded').addClass('collapsed').find('+ ul').slideUp('medium');
            e.find('+ ul').slideToggle('medium');
            };
        collapseAll();
        $('.cmenu').on('click', '> li > a', function () {
                var self = $(this);
                var menu = self.parent().parent();
                var el = self.find('+ ul');
                self.toggleClass('expanded').toggleClass('collapsed');
                handleCollapsibleMenu(self, el);
                });
        })
```

The collapsible menu shown [here (jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/jobowo/6bqjucan/) is far from perfect but it does what I need it to do ... except that I'd like to be able to collapse any previous levels when I expand a new level.

To illustrate (at the fiddle):

1. Click Level 1[1] to expand it.
2. Click Level 2[2] to expand it.
3. Click Level 2[3] to expand it. Notice that Level 2[2] now collapses. That is the behaviour that I want when....
4. Click Level 1[2]. You see that Level 1[1] remains expanded. What I'd like is for Level 1[1] to collapse when that happens (but obviously Level 1[2] remains expanded).

Note: I borrowed this js and css from a source and modified it to allow level 3. But then couldn't find the original source. If anyone recognizes this code please let me know the source. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your html: you have two `<ul>`s at the root level, when you only want one of these.

So remove the `</ul><ul class='cmenu'>` section in the middle. ie.

```
    ...
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class='cmenu'>
  <li><a>Level 1[2]</a>
    ...
```

is now just

```
    ...
  </li>
  <li><a>Level 1[2]</a>
    ...
```

This gives the structure at the root level of

```
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

rather than

```
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

which causes the problem.

Comment: Thanks for having a go at this but your solution doesn't seem to address the problem I want solved. Have you looked at the JSFiddle? The solution I believe I need is a change to the javascript. You're probably right that the html could be improved (I copied the script from elsewhere) but an html change won't solve my problem.

Comment: Yes I used the fiddle to test my solution. Here's an updated fiddle with the change above - https://jsfiddle.net/xepstft5/

Comment: Wow! Yes, that does appear to have answered my question but am baffled at present as to why this works. Will try to apply this to my actual more complicated menu but it does appear to be solved. Thanks so much!

Comment: I had gone through the JS and could find nothing wrong with code. To work however it expected to be able to go up a parent node in the tree and then back down again to hide other branches. The way you have it is two completely independent `<ul>` trees, so it was not able to go up and back down a separate one

Comment: And that's a most helpful explanation too. Am currently slogging through the PHP code that constructs the actual menu and this helps me understand what the issue was. Thanks again!

Comment: Postscript: Have taken @K Scandrett's excellent suggestion and stripped the script down to a more manageable and flexible version, shown at the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/6bqjucan/3/)